# importing module inside of a list comprehension in python

Tags: python, one-liner

The below program will show `loading` in console. Can we make it one line?
For that to happen we need to `import time` module inside of `list comprehension`.

How can we **import** module inside of `list comprehension`?

```
import time

[print(f"\rLoading... " + (('|', '/', '-', '\\')[i % 4]) + "\t", end="") or time.sleep(0.10) for i in range(100) ]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not importing the used packages at the beginning of the script?

Comment: No there is no reason. I want to know how to import modules inside of list comprehension?

Comment: Sounds more like something for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do it like this but this is not a recommendation:

```
[print(time:=__import__('time'), f"\033[2K\rLoading... " + (('|', '/', '-', '\\')[i % 4]) + "\t", end="") or time.sleep(0.10) for i in range(100)]
```

Comment:  Andy it works.